# HTML does not write any text

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a web and it has a header with a background image. After, I want to write some text, but for some reason i can't see it when i open the document. 
This is my html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">El sitio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Más info</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <!--So far, everything goes fine, but html doesn't show the h2, and p, but it show the section -->
            <section>
                <h2>Title!</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit leo nunc habitasse 
                 necscelerisque duis,tempus risus sapien id eget. </p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Plase help!! Thank you!

Comment: missing what inicio.css contains.  can not reproduce without

Comment: Are you sure the font should be loaded _after_ `inicio.css`?

Answer (score 0):

When I copy and paste it into a blank HTML file and open that in my browser, it shows for me. Potentially there is a caching issue or something with your browser?

Comment: That would be wird, because the same problem happens in two different computers, at home and at work..

Answer (score 0):

I tested your HTML code. Evertyhng is work. Something wrong with your browser. Changed it for test - firefox, chrome. ie . ect....

Comment: I have work with chrome, but i had this problem with two different computers, at my job and at home..

Comment: Probably: something wrong with inicio.css.

DELETE:    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio.css"> and Checked